# What is the English translation of brihadaranyaka-upanishad Verse 6.4.3-6?

Tags: translation-request

Brihadaranyaka-upanishad Verse 6.4.3-6 :

> तस्या वेदिरुपस्थः, लोमानि बर्हिः, चर्माधिषवणे—समिद्धो मध्यतः—तौ मुष्कौ; स यावान्ह वै वाजपेयेन यजमानस्य लोको भवति, तावानस्य लोको भवति य एवं विद्वानधोपहासं चरति; आसां स्त्रीणां सुकृतं वृङ्क्ते; अथ य इदमविद्वानधोपहासं चरति, आस्य स्त्रियः सुकृतं वृञ्जते ॥ ३ ॥
>
> एतद्ध स्म वै तद्विद्वानुद्दालक आरुणिराह; एतद्ध स्म वै तद्विद्वान्नाको मौद्गल्य आह; एतद्ध स्म वै तद्विद्वान्कुमारहारित आह, बहवो मर्या ब्राह्मणायना निरिन्द्रिया विसुकृतोऽस्माल्लोकात्प्रयन्ति, य इदमविद्वांसोऽधोपहासं चरन्तीति; बहु वा इदं सुप्तस्य वा जाग्रतो वा रेतः स्कन्दति ॥ ४ ॥
>
> तदभिमृशेत्, अनु वा मन्त्रयेत—
> यन्मेऽद्य रेतः पृथिवीमस्कान्त्सीत्, यदोषधीरप्यसरद्यदपः ।
> इदमहं तद्रेत आददे पुनर्मामैत्विन्द्रियम् पुनस्तेजः पुनर्भगः ।
> पुनरग्निर्धिष्ण्या यथास्थानं कल्पन्ताम्, इत्यनामिकाङ्गुष्ठाभ्यामादायान्तरेण स्तनौ वा भ्रुवौ वा निमृज्यात् ॥ ५ ॥
>
> अथ यद्युदक आत्मानं पश्येत्तदभिमन्त्रयेत—मयि तेज इन्द्रियं यशो द्रविणं सुकृतमिति; श्रीर्ह वा एषा स्त्रीणां यन्मलोद्वासाः; तस्मान्मलोद्वाससं यशस्विनीमभिक्रम्योपमन्त्रयेत ॥ ६ ॥
>
> tasyā vedirupasthaḥ, lomāni barhiḥ, carmādhiṣavaṇe—samiddho madhyataḥ—tau muṣkau; sa yāvānha vai vājapeyena yajamānasya loko bhavati, tāvānasya loko bhavati ya evaṃ vidvānadhopahāsaṃ carati; āsāṃ strīṇāṃ sukṛtaṃ vṛṅkte; atha ya idamavidvānadhopahāsaṃ carati, āsya striyaḥ sukṛtaṃ vṛñjate || 3 ||
>
> etaddha sma vai tadvidvānuddālaka āruṇirāha; etaddha sma vai tadvidvānnāko maudgalya āha; etaddha sma vai tadvidvānkumārahārita āha, bahavo maryā brāhmaṇāyanā nirindriyā visukṛto'smāllokātprayanti, ya idamavidvāṃso'dhopahāsaṃ carantīti; bahu vā idaṃ suptasya vā jāgrato vā retaḥ skandati || 4 ||
>
> tadabhimṛśet, anu vā mantrayeta—
> yanme'dya retaḥ pṛthivīmaskāntsīt, yadoṣadhīrapyasaradyadapaḥ |
> idamahaṃ tadreta ādade punarmāmaitvindriyam punastejaḥ punarbhagaḥ |
> punaragnirdhiṣṇyā yathāsthānaṃ kalpantām, ityanāmikāṅguṣṭhābhyāmādāyāntareṇa stanau vā bhruvau vā nimṛjyāt || 5 || [[SOURCE]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc122237.html)

What is the English translation of these verses. Thses verses are not translated in the website.

Comment: @Rickross I have given the source. It is the same. In the website there is no translation of this verse

Comment: Okay if that is the case then I'm deleting my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [translation of Hume](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15098.htm);

> 3. Her lap is a sacrificial altar; her hairs, the sacrificial grass; her skin, the soma-press. The two labia of the vulva are the fire in
>    the middle. Verily, indeed, as great as is the world of him who
>    sacrifices with the Vâjapeya ('Strength-libation') sacrifice, so great
>    is the world of him who practises sexual intercourse, knowing this; he
>    turns the good deeds of women to himself. But he who practises sexual
>    intercourse without knowing this-women turn his good deeds unto
>    themselves.
> 4. This, verily, indeed, it was that Uddâlaka Âruṅi knew when he said:--
>
> This, verily, indeed, it was that Nâka Maudgalya knew when he said:--
>
> This, verily, indeed, it was that Kumârahârita knew when he said:
> 'Many mortal men, Brahmans by descent, go forth from this world,
> impotent and devoid of merit, namely those who practise sexual
> intercourse without knowing this.'
>
> [If] even this much 1 semen is spilled, whether of one asleep or of
> one awake, [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iigAQ.png) then he should touch it, or [without touching]
> repeat:--
>
> 'What semen has of mine to earth been spilt now, Whate'er to herb has
> flowed, whate'er to water--
>
> This very semen I reclaim! Again to me let vigor come! Again, my
> strength; again, my glow! Again the altars and the fire Be found in
> their accustomed place!' Having spoken thus, he should take it with
> ring-finger and thumb, and rub it on between his breasts or his
> eye-brows.
>
> 6. Now, if one should see himself in water, he should recite over it the formula: 'In me be vigor, power, beauty, wealth, merit!'
>
> This, verily, indeed, is loveliness among women: when she has removed
> the clothes of her impurity. Therefore when she has removed the
> clothes of her impurity and is beautiful, one should approach and
> invite her.

The alternate translation is from [The Principal of Upanishad](https://archive.org/details/PrincipalUpanishads/page/n324/mode/1up) by Dr. Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Well stating below verse by verse translation:

**Verse 6.4.3:**

> तस्या वेदिरुपस्थो लोमानि बर्हिश्चर्माधिषवणे समिद्धो मध्यतस्तौ मुष्कौ स
> यावान् ह वै वाजपेयेन यजमानस्य लोको भवति तावानस्य लोको भवति य एवं
> विद्वानधोपहासं चरत्यासा स्त्रीणा सुकृतं वृङ्क्तेऽथ य इदमविद्वानधोपहासं
> चरत्याऽस्य स्त्रियः सुकृतं वृञ्जते॥

**Transliteration**

> tasyā vedirupastho lomāni barhiścarmādhiṣavaṇe samiddho madhyatastau
> muṣkau sa yāvān ha vai vājapeyena yajamānasya loko bhavati tāvānasya
> loko bhavati ya evaṁ vidvānadhopahāsaṁ caratyāsā strīṇā sukṛtaṁ
> vṛṅkte'tha ya idamavidvānadhopahāsaṁ caratyā'sya striyaḥ sukṛtaṁ
> vṛñjate||

**Meaning**

Her lap is the sacrificial altar, her hair the sacrificial grass, her skin within the organ the lighted fire; the two labia of the vulva are the two stones of the soma-press. He who, knowing this, practises sexual intercourse wins as great a world as is won through the Vijapeya sacrifice; he acquires for himself the fruit of the good deeds of the woman. But he who, without knowing this, practises sexual intercourse turns over to the woman his own good deeds.

**Verse 6.4.4:**

> एतद्ध स्म वै तद्विद्वानूद्दालक आरुनिराहैतद्ध स्म वै तद्विद्वान्नाको
> मौद्गल्य आहैतद्ध स्म वै तद्विद्वान्कुमारहारित आह बहवो मर्या
> ब्राह्मणायना निरिन्द्रिया विसुकृतोऽस्माल्लोकात्प्रयन्ति य
> इदमविद्वासोऽधोपहासं चरन्तीति बहु वा इद सुप्तस्य वा जाग्रतो वा रेतः
> स्कन्दति॥

**Transliteration**

> etaddha sma vai tadvidvānūddālaka ārunirāhaitaddha sma vai
> tadvidvānnāko maudgalya āhaitaddha sma vai tadvidvānkumārahārita āha
> bahavo maryā brāhmaṇāyanā nirindriyā visukṛto'smāllokātprayanti ya
> idamavidvāso'dhopahāsaṁ carantīti bahu vā ida suptasya vā jāgrato vā
> retaḥ skandati||

**Meaning**

Having known this, Uddalaka the son of Aruna, Naka the son of Mudgala and Kumara-harita said: "Many mortals, brahmins only in name, perform the sexual act withoutknowledge of what has been said and depart from this world impotent and without merit." Even if this much semen-of one asleep or of one awake-is spilled.

**Verse 6.4.5:**

> तदभिमृशेदनु वा मन्त्रयेत यन्मेऽद्य रेतः
> पृथिवीमस्कान्त्सीद्यदोषधीरप्यसरद्यदप। इदमहं तद्रेत आददे
> पुनर्मामैतुविन्द्रियं पुनस्तेजः पुनर्भगः। पुनरग्निर्धिष्ण्या यथास्थानं
> कल्पन्तामित्यानामिकाङ्गुष्ठाभ्यामादायान्तरेण स्तनौ वा भ्रुवौ वा
> निमृज्यात्॥

**Transliteration**

> tadabhimṛśedanu vā mantrayeta yanme'dya retaḥ
> pṛthivīmaskāntsīdyadoṣadhīrapyasaradyadapa| idamahaṁ tadreta ādade
> punarmāmaituvindriyaṁ punastejaḥ punarbhagaḥ| punaragnirdhiṣṇyā
> yathāsthānaṁ kalpantāmityānāmikāṅguṣṭhābhyāmādāyāntareṇastanau vā
> bhruvau vā nimṛjyāt||

**Meaning**

He should touch it and repeat the following mantra: "Whatever semen of mine has spilt on earth, whatever has flowed to plants, whatever to water, I reclaim it." With these words he should take the semen with his ring finger and thumb and rub it between his breasts or eyebrows, repeating the following mantra: "Let the semen return to me, let Vigour come to me again, let glow and good fortune come to me again. May the deities who dwell in the sacrificial fire put the semen back in its proper place."

**Verse 6.4.6:**

> अथ यद्युदक आत्मानं पश्येत्तदभिमन्त्रयेत मयि तेज इन्द्रियं यशो द्रविण
> सुकृतमिति श्रीर्ह वा एषा स्त्रीणां यन्मलोद्वासास्तस्मान्मलोद्वाससं
> यशस्विनीमभिक्रम्योपमन्त्रयेत॥

**Transliteration**

> atha yadyudaka ātmānaṁ paśyettadabhimantrayeta mayi teja indriyaṁ yaśo
> draviṇa sukṛtamiti śrīrha vā eṣā strīṇāṁ
> yanmalodvāsāstasmānmalodvāsasaṁ yaśasvinīmabhikramyopamantrayeta||

**Meaning**

Now, if a man sees himself (his reflection) in water, he should recite the following mantra: "May the gods bestow on me vigour, manhood, fame, wealth and merit." In praise of the wife who will bear him a son: She (his wife) has put on the soiled clothes of impurity; she is, verily, loveliness among women. Therefore when she has removed the clothes of impurity and appears beautiful, he should approach her and speak to her.

[Source](https://upanishads.org.in/upanishads/12) of the translations.

Comment: I have downvoted your response for only one reason - you need to give your source. The translation you have proffered is by Swami Nikhilananda in his translation of the Brihadanranyaka Upanishad, Vol 3 of his 'The Upanishads: A New Translation'

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

The online source you quote is from Swami Madhavananda's translation of the *Brihadaranyaka Upanishad* -it was a translation originally done about 100 years ago - by an Indian national under British rule. As it was meant for reading by general audiences, both Indian and Western, the literal translation might have caused some public consternation or political backlash as cultural and political morays were much more restrictive when it came to publications in English.

The translation proffered in Just_Do_It's answer is by Swami Nikhilananda, some 30 years later; and were done by an Indian stationed in America. He was not under the same restrictions that Madhavananda felt. In his Introduction to the *Brihadarnayaka Upanishad*, Nikhilananda writes:

> The fourth chapter of the sixth part of the Upanishad, consisting of twenty-eight verses, describes the religious rites by means of which a person may beget a qualified son. But such a rite can be performed only by one who has performed the Mantha rite described in preceding chapter. A warning is given against the waste of the vital fluid, which is the source of vitality, intelligence, and other spiritual virtues. Because of this fact control of carnal desires is extolled as a great spiritual asset. This is the basis of a life of continence practised by brahmacharins and sannyasins. After the birth of the child, the father invokes the blessings of the deity for the future greatness of the child and exhorts the latter to cultivate the Vedic wisdom. The chapter concludes with words of felicitation addressed to the noble mother of the worthy child.

Comment: Sir you didn't have translation.